# flickering black line in scrolling background

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scroll

I am working on an endless scrolling game. When I tested the background with a few sprites in the early development stages of the game, it was okay. Now that I've added all components including sound, menus, and everything else, there is a flickering black line in the background. I realized that when the scrolling speed is reduced the gap widens till it becomes a thick line (for very slow scrolling) and at extremely fast scrolling speeds it disappears. After researching on the issue I found a few posts that recommended the following:

1.
In ccConfig.h define this

```
#ifndef CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL
#define CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL 1
#endif
```

2.
Make sure spriteSheet, uses 2 pixel gap in sprite Spacing.

This didn't work. After comparing my earlier code since it was scrolling without any issues, I realized that the Heap Allocations was quiet high 5MB and increasing (running on an iPhone 5) as compared to under 1MB with the original background. After checking for memory leaks I found none. Please help.

Comment: Stretching texels is not a fix, not even a suitable workaround. The main cause of the black lines issue is not rounding position to the nearest integer positions every time you update it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but when I started varying the scrolling speed making different sprites determine how fast the background scrolls then the black line resurfaced. It was more pronounced when changing from the slowest to the fastest speed.

Comment: you may need to keep an "actual" position which has floating point numbers, and use that to calculate movement, then cast to int or round when assigning position. Also make the calculation once for the entire background, not for each background child node individually. They should all work with the exact same position rather than each recalculating it because that may introduce rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in previous apps was to overlap the two pieces of the background by a pixel. That have always solved the issue for me and has always been a quick and easy thing to do.